# передача массива в форме

Tags: html, вёрстка

Можно ли как то заставить передавать в форме массива (например таблицу)? Или для этого обязательно формировать данные отдельно и после `ajax`-ом отправлять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form>
  <input name="array[]" value="1"/>
  <input name="array[]" value="2"/>
  <input name="array[]" value="3"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, не знал такого)

Answer (score 0):

Можно так передать массив

```js
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="first_name">
    <input type="text" name="last_name">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

// Result of $_POST (PHP):
// array(
//     'first_name' => ''
//     'last_name' => ''
// )
```

Либо так

```js
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name[first]">
    <input type="text" name="name[last]">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

// Result of $_POST (PHP):
// array(
//     'name' => array(
//         'first' => ''
//         'last' => ''
//     )
// )
```